# Concatenation of items in list to use in WPF combobox Itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a List where a Person has Firstname and Surname. I want to concatenate Firstname and Surname to set combobox's itemsource and Display member Path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a view model, add a property with FirstName + Surname and use it in Display Member path.

Comment: Thanks Bro :)   I found this useful (y)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DataTemplate` for Concatinating two properties.
For Example.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding TaxName}" />
                <Run Text=" | @" />
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Rate}" />
                <Run  FontWeight="Bold" Text="%" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

it will be viewed as: `Service Tax | @12.36%` and bind its value on the code behind as

```
cmbTax.ItemsSource = taxes;
cmbTax.SelectedValuePath = "TaxID";
```